# Code for checking prime number giving segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have written the following code to check if a number is prime. I know that there are other, maybe better ways of doing i, but I just want to know what is wrong with this method. It is correctly identifying whether the number is prime or not, but in case i is prime, it is giving a segmentation error.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int);
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    prime(a);
    return 0;
}

void prime(int a)
{
    static int k=2;
    if((a%k==0)&&(a!=k))
        printf("Not a prime\n");
    else
    {
        k++;                   
        if(a==k)
            printf("Prime\n");     
        prime(a);
    }
}
```

Note: On trying to revise the code, I found that it makes no difference if you use a==k or k==a-1 in the else condition.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, your recursion never stops.

Secondly, the `static` state is a really bad idea. It makes the code hard to test and not thread-safe. What's worse, if you were to call `prime()` a second time, it would still keep state from the first call.

Finally, recursion is completely unnecessary here and can be trivially converted into iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Infinite recursion -> stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Your code never exits in the prime case.  You need:

```
if (a==k)
    printf("Prime\n");     
else
    prime(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(a==k)
        printf("Prime\n"); /* Q: What happens after you find it to be prime? */
    prime(a);              /* A: You test it for primeness again..? */
```

I think you meant this:

```
    if(a==k)
        printf("Prime\n");
    else
        prime(a);
```